# What is causing blacked-out windows on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a refurbished Lenovo ThinkPad T60 with

- Memory    2.9 GiB
- Processor Intel® Core™2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz × 2
- Graphics  ATI RV515
- GNOME     3.28.2
- OS type   64-bit
- Disk      36.4 GB

And I get blacked-out windows (not screen) in two different circumstances:

1. When booting up to the desktop (all icons are visible on the startup bar to the left, the to menu bar is visible and operating, and the normal reddish desktop screen with beaver symbol outline is visible behind the blacked-out window be it a Mozilla Firefox Window, A Thunderbird Window, A Midori Browser Window or any of the windows that open with various software in the Ubuntu program).
2. Sometimes after using the computer the windows go from whatever characters or images visible on a mainly white background to blacked out window or windows with no images visible on the blacked out portion.

In either circumstance there seems to be no way of correcting or reverting to a visible characters and/or images window and so I reboot the machine which starts with a mostly dark screen along with the Intel logo, Lenovo  name and ThinkPad "To interrupt normal startup, press the blue ThinkVantage button"

That is followed by a reddish screen that is titled: GNU GRUB version 2.02
and below is a menu of Ubuntu startup choices:

```
Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

Memory test (memtest86+)

Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04)

Advanced options for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sda1)
```

So I hit the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> once and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button and got these menu items:

- Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-55-generic
- Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-55-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
- Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-54-generic (recovery mode)

I then hit the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> twice and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

And a purple screen opens with these three lines in the upper left corner:

```
Loading Linux 4.15.0-54-generic...

Loading initial ramdisk...

...
```

and after maybe 15 seconds

A dark screen  with the word Ubuntu and 5 white dots beneath it and each dot in succession every second or so turning red and then the red dots turn white one by one and then red and before all the dots turn red the screen goes dark.

Then the desktop comes up looking normal and after choosing a program such as the Firefox browser, either it comes up in normal mode that one can see characters and images  or a blacked-out window opens.

I often feel like I'm rolling dice hoping to get a normal operating system  instead of a malfunctioning one.

So my question is in two parts:

1. What is causing the windows to black-out?
2. What can I do to stop the windows from blacking out?